# Tableau can be used as a big datastore as well?

Tags: tableau

Company wants to use Tableau solution for visual reporting. The inputs are various files. The plan is to use latest SQL Server as database and server.

Q. Does Tableau has their own database ? Can perform own reporting without SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tableau Desktop does not have a own database.** Tableau only connects to data sources like text files, databases, excel, .csv, etc. After connecting to a data source, Tableau can "extract" that data into a Tableau Data Extract file [(check this link if you want to know how it works)](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2014/7/understanding-tableau-data-extracts-part1) that is both compressed and represented in a columnar store format in data prep, in data preparation section in tableau you can pivot your data, applied filter, applied joins just like SQL, add various databases, files, tables and you could join, and more.

Tableau is not perfect and has limitations in my last job I can't see all the database because Tableau can't display to me so not use Tableau for exploratory analysis in big-data or big-dataset.

Tableau has buil-in tools that could do this labour more easy and give to you a complete picture of your data for example:

[image]

> **2nd Question: Yes. You can perform your own report without any relational database management system**